# Nexus automatic sync with Proxy Repository

Tags: maven, gradle, proxy, dependencies, nexus

I have an external Nexus Open Source version repository, that is connected to an internal one trough proxy repository.

I want to automatically sync the repo with the latest releases and latest snapshots without the need to request them trough a build.

I know there is a capability "Smart Proxy feature" but I can't enable it as we are not using the professional version.

Can you suggest other "smart" and "clean" ways to achieve this?

I was thinking I can create a Jenkins job running every 5 minutes that requests the dependencies thorugh a build using placeholders such as latest release and latest snaphost but i want to know if there is any easier and cleaner way to achieve this.

If my question is not clear please let me know.

Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642594/auto-mirroring-nexus-proxy-repository) but no useful replies.

Comment: If this is a Nexus 2 server, you can also think about syncing on file level.

Comment: You mean filesytem level? Yeah I know but I think it's even less clean that create a project to refresh the dependencies every once in a while

Comment: The advantage: There are automatic free file synchronisation tools and Nexus stores its data in files. You regular reindexing, though.

Comment: Maybe my idea is not so good after all because it will most likely cause problems with Nexus indices ...

Comment: I would also be interested _why_ you want this behaviour (instead of the "normal" proxy behaviour)?

Comment: Your idea is not bad, but we already have similar process for ivy remote repo and unfortunately network issues are constantly impacting the sync because we work in a context where network unstability is constant. For your second question about why, easy answer is: because our customer want this! detailed answer is that having releases already cached will speed up the sync between internal and external repositories as the build request won't download the actual dependencies (that are already cached) but simply the checksum to check if there are newer one. Does this make sense to you?